# Here FindSequence Limit Waypoint

Tags: here-api

I need to get an optimized sequence of a route with up to max 120 waypoints.

I was trying to use "Here API" but with trial plan (I guess) even though I enter 10/20/30/40 destinations (waypoints), it always calculates only the top 5 destinations.

Is a plan problem?

thanks!

Maurizio

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it successfully with up to 119 waypoints. I'm a customer (not trial).

Endpoint I'm using:  https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json

Hope it helps

Comment: It's fast. A few seconds maybe